# Display line numbers on left margin in Emacs

Tags: emacs, plugins

I know that there's already a question of the same type on here, and I did take a look at it. The thing is, what is suggested there leads to line numbers being displayed right next to the code, with not a single space in between which annoys me a lot. Therefore, I wanted to try a different approach.

I'm trying to use the [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/line-num.el) code I found on the emacs wiki. I created the `line-num.el` file , put it in `~/.emacs.d/plugins` and then modified the `~/.emacs` file as follows:

> (add-to-list 'load-path"~/.emacs.d/plugins")
>
> (require 'line-num.el)

But when I start emacs, I don't see any line numbers.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but seen this page? http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers  It lists several packages with discussion.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.  First, to properly require the package, you don't use the `.el` at the end:

```
(require 'line-num)
```

Second, you need to turn it on, generally by using a hook:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'turn-on-line-numbers-display)
```

Add a line for each of the programming modes you want to have line numbers.

That said, the `line-num` package says that the `setnu` package provides better functionality, so you might want to try that, as well as the `setnu+` addition.  See [the wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc9) for how to get it and install it.

And, there's the built-in `linum-mode` that you found.  To turn that on for all buffers associated with files, you can do:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'linum-on)
```

Comment: I managed to use the built in line number module `linum-mode`, but I wanted to modify the .emacs file so that that command is run on startup. Could you tell me how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use linum-mode's `linum-format` variable to add a space on the margin: `(setq linum-format "%d ")`